# using double hyphens

Tags: grammar

I'm translating some news items from Arabic into English and I want to know if I can use two hyphenated compound nouns in the same sentence :

- The 47- member state Geneve-based council has adopted a British resolution.
- The 47-member state council, based in Geneve, has adopted a British Resolution.
- The 47-member state council, which is based in Geneve, has adopted ...

Thanks in advance .

Comment: No problem with the hyphens, but you should really pay more attention to using your spaces. The only way multiple hyphens become confusing is when you use spaces around them carelessly. Around hyphens in a hyphenated word, don't use spaces. Before a comma or similar symbols, don;t use a space, but _do_ use one after them. When you use m-dashes to set off part of a sentence — similar to brackets — use spaces before and after them.

Comment: @oerkelens The last part of your comment depends on your style guide and preference. Some would say to use thin spaces or hair spaces around em dashes; others would say to use regular spaces; and others (like CMoS) would say use no spaces at all. I’m not aware of anyone who would say that for en dashes, though.

Answer (score 1):

Either of the first two could be used with modification. The third is unnecessarily verbose.

There is certainly no reason why two hyphenated compound nouns cannot be used in the same sentence, but I would modify slightly and introduce some punctuation.

In both of them a further hyphen is required between "member" and "state".

In the first, I would add a comma after "state", and another after "council".

So the two recommended possibilities are:

***The 47-member-state, Geneva-based council...***
or ***The 47-member-state council, based in Geneva...***

Comment: I really appreciate your effort , thank you very much .

Comment: @EdwinAshworth You are quite right - an additional hyphen is called for, and I have substantially edited my answer.

Comment: I'd think that 'state council' is near enough a compound not to need a hyphen, but there must be no intervening words.

Comment: I disagree with the extra added hyphen being necessary. An extra hyphen is certainly _possible_, but it means something else then. There’s a difference between a 47-member state council and a 47-member-state council: the former is a state council that has 47 members; the latter is a council that that has 47 member states. The former would have to be a Swiss council of some kind here, while the latter would have to be an international council (say, a UN council) that happens to be based in Switzerland. (I would also put _Geneva-based_ first for euphony, but I’d say there’s more leeway there.)